# Classification algorithms, which classifications can be evaluated as percentages

Tags: algorithm, classification

I'm implementing different classification algorithms to predict the outcome of soccer matches (Home, draw or away). In order to compare the classifications of different classifiers, the classifications from the classifiers are evaluated as percentages.

At the moment I'm using k-nearest neighbours (and counting neighbours of different classes to convert to percentages) and the naive bayes.

Besides the knn and naive bayes, which classifiers can be used for this task?

Answer (score 0):

Support Vector Machines are probably the most common classifiers appearing in the literature right now,  and there are several Random Forest classification schemes as well.  Look at [Weka](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/) for a package supporting those methods (and others) in Java.  Also, R has a lot of tools for machine learning, so you could quickly test other algorithms without having to implement them yourself.

Answer (score 0):

A logistic model will naturally express itself as probabilities. For soccer, quite a few people have modelled the goals scored by each side as a Poisson process, with rate depending on the relative strengths of the defense and offense concerned.